# Android Data binding - Error:(119, 29) Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. main_radio_subscribe is missing it

Tags: android, android-databinding

I been trying to control the visibility of a view using the  Implicit Attribute Listeners([reference](https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/2-way-data-binding-on-android/)) in android data binding which allows to access views by id and access attributes like checked, visible etc ..., however when trying to use this, it throws an error like so

```
Error:(119, 29) Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. addTodo_switch_remind is missing it
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/addTodo_switch_remind"
        style="@style/MediumTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addTodo_space_project"
        android:text="@string/add_todo_remind_label"
        android:textOff="@string/generic_no_text"
        android:textOn="@string/generic_yes_text" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/addTodo_space_remind"
        style="@style/FormsSpacingStyle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addTodo_switch_remind" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/addTodo_space_remind"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/grid_box_single"
        android:visibility="@{addTodo_switch_remind.checked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}">
```

Comment: post the xml and the BindingAdapter you are using for that

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like the implicit Attribute listeners use camel case when it is used in the expressions, thanks to this [post](https://plus.google.com/+NickButcher/posts/Uvx3EhxV9K7) I figured it out.

```
<!--Recurring Reminder -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/addTodo_switch_remind"
            style="@style/MediumTextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/addTodo_space_project"
            android:text="@string/add_todo_remind_label"
            android:textOff="@string/generic_no_text"
            android:textOn="@string/generic_yes_text" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.Space
            android:id="@+id/addTodo_space_remind"
            style="@style/FormsSpacingStyle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/addTodo_switch_remind" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/addTodo_space_remind"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/grid_box_single"
            android:visibility="@{addTodoSwitchRemind.checked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}">
```

Documenting for others who have the same issue

Comment: addTodoSwitchRemind should be the name of your model view class.

Comment: @Blackbelt - Nope that is the id of the appcompact checkbox

Answer (score 51):

As you use `View.VISIBLE` / `View.GONE` in your .xml file, you should import the `View` type by doing adding **`<import type="android.view.View"/>`** in the data section like the following:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="xx.xx.MyViewModel"/>
</data>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1**: create [BindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#custom_setters):

```
@BindingAdapter("android:visibility")
public static void setVisibility(final View view, @IdRes int layourId) {
    SwitchCompat switcher = (SwitchCompat)view.getRootView().findViewById(layourId)
    switcher.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            view.setVisibility(isChecked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: import `R` class in databinding data section at you *layout.xml*:

```
<data>
     <import type="example.package.R"/>
</data>
```

**Step 3**: bind custom view to your switcher like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/addTodo_switch_remind"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:visibility="@{R.id.addTodo_switch_remind">
```