# android:visibility Not working with visibile or gone options

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I am trying to show and hide an element based on a boolean. In my xml I have the following:

```
android:visibility="@{viewModel.interfaceEnable ? visible : gone}"
```

`viewModel.interfaceEnable` is an ObservableField as as such: `var interfaceEnable = ObservableField<Boolean>()`. And `visible` and `gone` are values for the `android:visibility` attribute. But I am getting this error:

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. visibile is missing it
```

Why is this attribute not settable this method?

Comment: Can you post full xml please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Data binding - Error:(119, 29) Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. main\_radio\_subscribe is missing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609252/android-data-binding-error119-29-identifiers-must-have-user-defined-types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visible and gone are still constants in View (`View.VISIBLE` and `View.GONE`) and that statement should reflect it

```
android:visibility="@{viewModel.interfaceEnable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

alternatively you cold use a simple binding adapter for it. EG

```
 @BindingAdapter("toVisibility")
 fun View.toVisibility(visible: Boolean) {
    visibility = if (visible) { View.VISIBLE } else { View.GONE }
 }
```

and in your xml use

```
toVisibility="@{viewModel.interfaceEnable}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `View` as follows to use the constants:

```
android:visibility="@{viewModel.interfaceEnable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

For more information check the [Visibility documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Visibility) that you can use [`View.GONE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE), [`View.INVISIBLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) and [`View.VISIBLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE)

Also make sure you use the correct import type for this as follows

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable
        name="anyName"
        type="com.example.AnyName"/>
</data>
```

Comment: the `import` indeed directly addresses the error message.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yep, exactly.